Reworking home network to reach LAN from WAN
So I have thought the last few days about finally reworking my Network here at home to get the Firewall between router and Server.
The problem is that my Network is not in a state where I can just move everything behind the firewall, so I want to get to a in-between goal of having security for my server, and if something happens, at least security for the rest of my Network.
I work in IT, but still an apprentice, and haven't configured a Firewall myself yet.
So take this image as my Current Infrastructure:

The Double line is not yet established, but planned, (so the current connection can be severed) thats why i have this question.
If i set the basics up, i can connect from LAN (server) to WAN without problems. That works Fine.
But i have a NAS, Mailserver, Website, Gameservers and some more things on my Server, that i need to selectively reach from WAN, but things like my NAS, i need to only reach from my internal Network Range (192.168.178.x)
So how can i access the server (Port1, LAN, 192.168.1.x) From my Desktop(192.168.178.250)?
A colleague from work told me to disable the DHCP from my Fritzbox, give it the IP 192.168.178.2, let the Firewall Create DHCP on Port2, WAN, with 192.168.178.1 as the IP for the NIC, enable exposed host for the FW(192.168.178.1) and pointing the gateway to 192.168.178.2 (the new IP for the Fritzbox).
Would this give me the possibility by creating the rule from WAN,any to LAN,any with any service, to get a connection from my 192.168.178.x network to the 192.168.1.x network?

Your colleagues suggestion a good one, but keeping mind you might have to also implement port forwarding through the firewall- which you'll need to be careful with. I would also consider implementing a DMZ (Demilitarized Zone) to further segregate your server from the rest of the network. This will certainly make things smoother but tread carefully. Being particularly interested in security myself, how important is your network security (local and remote threats) to you? I do have a few small security nit-picks with your current setup...

Please, if you have some remarks about my setup please tell me, im always open to learn more on how to set up better security.
Im not super paranoid about the security, i mean i know that i probably shouldnt set up a domain that points to my IP and have a website and mailserver open. But its a nice project and im kinda sure im not the main target to try and breach. My Fritzbox has access from outside disabled, and my most important NAS, is only reachable with my Computers IP.
Mhhhh port forwarding, need to see how to set that up then, and filter true WAN from internal IP's

Your colleague’s suggestion (disabling DHCP on the Fritzbox, setting the firewall to handle DHCP, and configuring the firewall as an exposed host) actually seems pretty sound, but take note of the following:

Relying too heavily on an exposed host (DMZ) can be unsafe because it opens up the firewall to all incoming WAN traffic.


If you can, use port forwarding to control WAN access instead, like I said in my comment.

Regardless of whether you decide to do the former or not, make sure to use firewall rules to limit external access to only necessary services (like your web server or mail server). Definitely block or restrict sensitive services, such as the NAS, from WAN access.



Not security related, but avoiding double NAT by placing the Fritzbox in bridge mode can reduce connectivity issues, for obvious reasons.


Yeah, i would never use a any-any rule for the firewall. What ive planned to do is giving it a more granular structure, not going by interfaces, but groups, so i have for example the InternetWAN, it would only get the ports for gameserver, website, smtp.
Something like NAS i would block for every device but the ones i use.
It needs a quite granular structure, but with the exposed host option, i try to avoid the double NAT. Tho i still need to see how i can Properly setup the NAT rules on my xg firewall
